# Best way to trigger/cascade command using Axon Framework

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, axon

Using Axon Sramework, what is the best way to trigger a command after another command as succeeded.
For example, a command will create an `Aggregate` (and then the entity, after the entity has been created, we need to create another aggregate/entity on another domain (as a child of the first entity for example).

The second entity has to be created using a command on an aggregate, but where to initiate the second command ? in the `@EventSourcingHandler` of the first aggregate ? in the `@EventHandler` when saving the first entity ? by using `Saga` ?

Another point/question :
What is the best way to trigger a command from a query. For example, I have a query to get some records and if a record does not exist, I would like to create it automatically and then send the result back from the query method. Do I have to use the command gateway to send a create command from the query handler class and then wait for the result ? or is there another way to do it ?

Thanks for support and help.

Alexandre

Comment: What do you mean by "as a child of the first entity for example"? How is this second entity a child of the first entity in another domain/bounded context?

Answer (score 1):

> what is the best way to trigger a command after another command as
> succeeded?

Ignoring the "best way" in that question, you are most likely looking for a process manager. In Axon Framework, those are called [Sagas](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/sagas).

> What is the best way to trigger a command from a query. For example, I have a query to get some records and if a record does not exist, I would like to create it automatically

I would be very, very careful doing something like that.

First of all, what if you receive the same query multiple times in a short time? How do you know if the command has been already sent or not?

Second, you don't want to wait for an update while responding to a query as you can't know how long that would take or if it will happen at all.

One alternative is to use a [subscription query](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/queries/query-dispatchers#subscription-queries). Indicate in the initial response that data is incomplete and let the client trigger an update via appropriate command flow. Since the client is subscribed to the query, it will receive the update once it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

> Using the Axon framework, what is the best way to trigger a command after another command as succeeded. For example, a command will create an aggregate (and then the entity,9 after the entity has been created, we need to create another aggregate/entity on another domain (as a child of the first entity for example).

First of all, a command NEVER creates an aggregate. A command defines the intention to create an aggregate. The command-constructor should verify if all conditions to create the aggregate are met and then send an aggregate-created-event. This event actually creates the aggregate and initializes its state. Check the Axon documentation for commands and events for more details about this. Note also that only events are stored on the event store, commands are fire and forget.

The aggregate-created-event sent by the aggregate can create the entity using an event handler on a projection for example (I assume the entity exist in the scope of a projection in a read model).

Since you mention the creation of the entity is followed by another aggregate being created, sagas (as mentioned by Milen) come into play. The saga is started by the event-created-event of the first aggregate and sends a create-command for the second aggregate. Then the same flow as for the first aggregate repeats (verify all conditions to create the aggregate and send the creation event).

If you need to have the guarantee the first entity exists before the second aggregate will be created, you could tried to send a kind of first-entity-created-event in the projection, catch this event in your saga and let this saga handler fire the command to create the second aggregate. I don't know for sure if projection's are allowed to send commands although I cannot imagine why not... Domain events can be used to cross boundaries of a microservice.

It sounds more complicated than it is, but be sure to check the chapter about sagas in the Axon docs as well.

> The second entity has to be created using a command on an aggregate, but where to initiate the second command ? in the @EventSourcingHandler of the first aggregate ? in the @EventHandler when saving the first entity ? by using Saga ?

I think it is a bit weird to create entities using commands on an aggregate. Aggregates handle commands related to the state changes they allow from business point of view. What is your intention to do so? Entities (assuming you mean JPA entities), as mentioned earlier, are used to "summarize" all events that lead to the current state of the aggregate and often live in the read model (in a CQRS architecture). @EventHandlers listen for events and update the entity correspondingly in a projection typically. @EventSourcingHandler live on the aggregate to respond to events to update the current state of the aggregate which has to be known to verify the validity of future commands. Commands are very closely related to business processes' related actions performed on the aggregate.

I hope this clarifies your questions a bit although I fear they just create more questions ;-)